# Issue running javascript library (photo sphere viewer)

Tags: javascript, npm, photosphereviewer

I wanted to use [Photo Sphere Viewer](http://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org/) in my project.
So I ran

```
npm i photo-sphere-viewer
```

It appears to have downloaded the modules.

Then inside my project I did:

```
import PhotoSphereViewer from 'photo-sphere-viewer/dist/photo-sphere-viewer';
```

But I get error:

Failed to compile.

```
Error in ./~/photo-sphere-viewer/dist/photo-sphere-viewer.js
Module not found: 'D.js' in /home/ghy/WebstormProjects/mia-map/node_modules/photo-sphere-viewer/dist

 @ ./~/photo-sphere-viewer/dist/photo-sphere-viewer.js 9:4-55
```

Can anyone help me spot what is wrong?

PS. I think following line is causing issue (inside photo-sphere-viewer.js):

```
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(['three', 'D.js', 'uevent', 'doT'], factory);
  }
```

but I am even surprised why it enters inside this `if` as I didn't know I had `require.js` installed.

PPS. I have a react application created by `create-react-app`

Answer (score 1):

Mine works with webpack using:

```
import { Viewer } from 'photo-sphere-viewer';

const viewer = new Viewer({
    container: document.querySelector('#viewer'),
    panorama: 'path/to/photo.jpg'
});
```

You can install with npm or yarn

```
npm install photo-sphere-viewer
# or
yarn add photo-sphere-viewer
```